# TEB representation for ARM64, xpr register

Tags: assembly, windbg, arm64, windows-kernel

I'm trying to figure out ARM64 architecture using ARM build of Windows 11. I can see that the [KeGetCurrentIrql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-kegetcurrentirql) function is converted to:

```
ldrb    w0, [xpr, #0x38]
ret
```

If I understand this correctly, `xpr` register is `x18`, and thus the `ldrb` instruction reads a byte from the memory address taken from the `x18` register, plus `0x38` offset.

So, when I triggered a breakpont on the `ldrb` instruction, I'm trying the following in WinDbg:

```
kd> r x18
x18=0000000000000000
```

But how can it be, `x18` is 0? TEB cannot be 0. What am I missing there?

If I do:

```
kd> !teb
TEB at 0000003d7af95000
...
```

Comment: `x18` only holds the TEB in user mode.  You are presumably not in user mode when calling `KeGetCurrentIrql`; in kernel mode, the register holds KPCL instead.  (I have no idea whether 0 is a reasonable value for KPCL.)

Comment: @DanielA.White - Does the [windows-kernel] tag not apply?  I added it (based on the question asking about a kernel function, and a comment pointing out that this was in kernel mode).  Then I checked the edit history and saw you had removed it.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @jasonharper - *holds `KPCL` instead* - really `KPCR`. declared in [*ntddk.h*](https://codemachine.com/downloads/win10.1511/ntddk.h) and `KIRQL CurrentIrql;                  // +038` exactly have `0x38` offset here. and of course pointer to `KPCR` never 0. in user mode it really hold `TEB` - `(struct _TEB *)__getReg(18);` arm64 implementation of  `NtCurrentTeb`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had the windows-kernel tag, but then someone removed it. Anyway, yes, this is called from the kernel mode. And to what RbMm mentioned, yes, this appears to be correct. I wonder if this is a bug in WinDbg that it's reporting `x18` as 0?

Comment: Although thread-local-storage has nothing to do with this question. I didn't add it.

Comment: I added the TLS tag.  But now that you point it out, I realized that was an error.  TLS on Windows can involve getting a pointer from the TEB, but there are other reasons to access the TEB.

Comment: My bad folks, it is indeed `_KPCR`, but still I'm not sure why WinDbg gives me `x18` as 0. It can't be 0, can it?

Comment: Pointer to KPCR is never 0. Windows create one KPCR per core, every this object have some kernel mode address and of course not 0

Comment: Yeah, I got to the bottom of it. WinDbg resets it to 0 even though the actual X18 is not 0. To get its actual value one needs to use pseudo-register `@$pcr` in WinDbg.